# show events in next seven days when the event is having start and end date using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

### table structure

```
 CREATE TABLE `events` (
`id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`heading` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`start_date` DATE NOT NULL ,
`end_date` DATE NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

i have a table events with heading,start_date and end_date. the problem is i want to show all the records which falls under next seven days either it can be start_date or end_date. sometimes the end date will not be specified because it will be to be announced, so that end_date will be 0000-00-00 and that is also to be taken care.

Comment: so when you pass 0000-00-00 as end date then what you expect?

Comment: the ending of the event is to be announced and it is also to be shown under next seven days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `events`
WHERE 
/*Select with no end date */
(`end_date` = '0000-00-00' AND `start_date` BETWEEN NOW() AND ADDDATE(NOW(), 7)) 
/* SELECT ON THIS DAY */
OR NOW() BETWEEN `start_date` AND `end_date` 
/* SELECT ON NEXT 7 DAY */
OR ADDDATE(NOW(), 7) BETWEEN `start_date` AND `end_date`
```

Comment: CHORTik thanks for the reply, its working when i have start_date and end_date, but its not fetching all the records where the end date is 0000-00-00

Comment: ok got it,added one more condition to fetch all the dates with end as 0000-00-00